# Function to generate screen shots creates exception

Tags: c#, winforms

I have this function which is called on a timer. The screen shots are then used to check certain pixels for color. I am also using serial communication with an Arduino if that is relevant.

```
    private Bitmap Screenshot()
    {
        Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
        bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
                                   Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot);
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
        return bmpScreenshot;
    }
```

The problem i'm getting is that after it running for a while I get the following error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception'
>   occurred in System.Drawing.dll

Additional information: Overlapped I/O operation is in progress

I cannot seem to find anywhere what the source of this is or how to fix it, any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Seems like you are calling Screenshot too fast.

Comment: What is the timer's intervall? do you send the image over the line? do you store it? do you overwrite the previous version?

Comment: How often is your timer firing? It's clearly too often. (It does little good to post code when it's not your real code. The snippet you posted wouldn't compile, because of the line containing `new Bitmap`.)

Comment: @KenWhite It does compile. Use horizontal scrollbar :)

Comment: @EZI: Ah, you're right. It's just horribly formatted. Fixed. Thanks. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Graphics is a class known to have strange behavior if you do not dispose of its resources properly. You need to dispose the Graphics object that you created in the method.

```
private Bitmap Screenshot()
{
    Bitmap bmpScreenshot;
    bmpScreenshot = new Bitmap(Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width, 
                               Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height);
    using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmpScreenshot))
    {
        g.CopyFromScreen(0, 0, 0, 0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Size);
        return bmpScreenshot;
    }
}
```

Also be sure you also dispose the `Bitmap` in the calling function when you are done with it too.

I don't know if this will fix your problem, but it is possible that it could.